# How to detect and enable a bluetooth adapter?

Tags: linux, bluetooth

I'm developing an embedded Linux with our EVM board and we want to support a USB bluetooth dongle.
After insert the dongle, we can use some command to enable it and it's no problem.

For example,
#hciconfig hci0 up
#hcitool scan

But for user, we need our Linux can detect and enable the dongle automatically.
Can anyone provide some information or example how to do this?

I also tried to use inotify to see if can detect usb BT dongle insert or not under /sys/bus/drivers/btusb, but it seems useless.

Thanks.

Comment: Insert ... what kind of connector? USB? GPIO pins on your EVM? As for the "pick up automagically and enable" - that may, in part, depend on the actual flavour of your embedded Linux. Please add more detail to your question (edit, don't comment).

Comment: We use USB BT dongle. I update the info in original post.

Comment: What about the `dmesg` output? lsusb? Does your distro use `systemd`? The old `udev` system?

Comment: For our user, they have no console to use.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This question might be better on https://superuser.com/. There is not much detail in your question but it sounds like you might be looking for `udev`. https://opensource.com/article/18/11/udev. I'd also point out that the `hci*` tools were  [deprecated by the BlueZ](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) project in 2017. They have been replaced with `btmgmt` and `bluetoothctl`.

Answer (score 0):

Linux kernel would log every devices connected to it during startup and you can find them with below command .

```
dmesg | grep -i blue
```